# Show Context Menu With Short Click not Long Click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, contextmenu, imageview

I have a problem with the contextual menu, I have a control "ImageButton" when you make a long click displays a context menu.

I need to display the contextual menu with a short click, not a long click, is this possible?

This is the code I currently use, the menu works perfectly.

```
    private ImageView btnRutas;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.fclientes);

        btnRutas =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnRutas);

        btnRutas.setOnClickListener(this);

        registerForContextMenu(btnRutas); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        if(v.getId()== R.id.btnRutas) {

            menu.setHeaderIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Rutas");
            menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Ruta 1");

        } 

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

    case 0:

        function();

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use an onClickListener() as part of the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    //Usual Activity Stuff
    View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.view); 
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 public void onClick(View v) {
  super.onClick(v);
  this.openContextMenu(v);
 }
}
```

Instead of creating a new View specifically for this, I guess you would use whatever View you wanted this to apply to. I hope this is what you were going for and that this helps.

Comment: HURRAY! best of luck coding :0)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use popup menu instead of context menu. Check documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus, or do it like this:

```
  private void showMenu(View v){
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item1:
                    //your code
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item2:
                    //your code
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item3:
                    //your code
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

Call this method in onClickListener of your button and pass your button.

Answer (score 0):

Without adding any OnClickListener in the code,you can do it only in the xml.Just go to  your ImageView and add:

```
android:onClick="openContextMenu"
```

Here is an example.

```
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnRutas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="openContextMenu" />
```